# Would this be able to glide?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, flight

On my planet there is a fish that acts as a pollinator. It has 2 fins, one on each side. When it jumps from the water both it’s fins spilt into two revealing a web of skin. [image]

[image]

The reason it does this is to quickly travel above the water where it’s easier to spot its food source.

It works by using a dolphin like tail to jump from the water when it’s fins split, it uses this skin webbing to catch the wind and propel it forward.

I’m just wondering if this would work. If not do you have any suggestions on what I could change? Or is it just to far fetched?

Comment: Just in case anyone was wondering, the gravity is slightly higher than earths, wind and storms are very common.

Comment: Might want to look at YouTube for "flying squid" -- they make flying fish look like a seed blowing on the breeze.

Comment: If you can make a semi-functional paper airplane that approximates this shape, then it can glide. Just based on the drawings, you might want to make the wings a little bigger.

Comment: This looks to me like a flying fish.   https://www.nwf.org/Educational-Resources/Wildlife-Guide/Fish/Flying-Fish

Comment: *"It has 2 fins, one on each side"* why this two-layered wing construct ? When you want lift, better place all 4 wings alongside the body. A flying animal is not a biplane aircraft, with propellors for thrust, providing the upper wing with upward airflow. In your construct, the lower wing is blocking upward  airflow of the upper wing.

Comment: The wings aren’t necessarily overlapped as the lower wing moves forwards and slightly lowers and the higher wing does the opposite.

Comment: Your planet doesn't happent to be Earth, does it?  Because that's a pretty good description of a flying fish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_fish  Probably not going to be much use as a pollinator if it just glides, though, since that makes it difficult to seek out flowers.

Comment: First of all the only thing it has in common is the fact that it glides, not to mention its wings are vastly different. Second of all pollination isn’t limited to just flowers. Please ask for information before you just judge. In the oceans of my planet there is a kelp like plant that floats on the surface of the water, this is what it pollinates. It is hard to spot underwater due to the dense oceans and hard to travel from area to area because of the abundance of predators in the area. If you wish to have a further explanation of the planet please ask me and I will answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything glides, including bricks.

Aerodynamics has a weird fixation on steady state, i.e. that a situation one decribes (angle of attack, speed...) stays that way. This is not necessary, strictly.

If you allow for change, an object that has a 'bad' static glide ratio may still, for instance, make a soft landing - see for example the space shuttle. It relies on constantly exchanging airspeed for lift by changing your angle of attack, which obviously only works until there is no speed left - at that point you should be on the ground (in your case on the water).

A fish, with its high weight/wing ratio will not be a good glider in absolute terms, but there is nothing stopping nature to evolve a fish that jumps from the water and then softly land on a nearby sea-rose (or however that pollination is supposed to work).

However you mentioned -'catching wind from behind' - this would imply zero, or even negative, airspeed, which is a no-no for gliders. Two possibilities: jump very fast from the water, giving you airspeed even along the winds direction, and use the wind to achieve farther glides, or: jump against the wind, and use the 'free' initial airspeed for an even softer landing (while not achieving that much glide-length).

Nature can do much better than the space shuttle re:'being mostly a brick and still land softly' because soft structures are much better at adapting to different angles of attack, and one can optimise the wing geometry in many different ways, not only by flaps and slats.

If you have any other element that can exchange forces with something apart from the air, you can leverage that: you might do work against a fluid inside the fish, perhaps for some rotatory mechanism - this would of course only be a temporary measure, until the fluid is spun up, or you could dip a fin into the water, and leverage the delta between airspeed and waterspeed (like a kite surfer). If you allow for magic, or magic-like physics, there could be help from electrostatics or magnetic fields. Any force that is not downwards, and not colinear with the wind direction, can be used as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.